# To show product on a particular category

Tags: magento

I am trying to show a customer his active subscription that he has purchased till a date. I have a category called my subscription what I want is that when a user logged in and he purchased a subscription further he goes to another category called my subscription where he can see his subscription I want to show his subscription (i.e virtual products) on that category. Right now neglecting the logged in condition I just want that user fetch sku from database and show at any category where I want.

I am not able to bring the product as a whole but able to collect product information.

Comment: Build a custom module and post your code so we can see that you have an understanding of the issue and have attempted to try and solve it. As a hint you will need a module with a custom block (this should get the products the customer has purchased and return as a collection). You can then include your block via xml layout updates on whatever category or page you so desire.

Comment: actually i have some tried some code at view.phtml from where i am able to get product info at whole bt i want a product not the product info only.anyways thanx for your suggestion @ashley swatton